# comments in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

I am unable to create comments. I tried using `//` and `*/` but it's still showing the comments as normal text. I am using visual studio code as IDE [image: this is the output I am getting]

Comment: your file type is html. Try using html comments syntax instead

Comment: It seems like you are commenting inside an HTML tag, use this instead: `<!-- I'm a comment in HTML --> `

Comment: Are the comments inside the `<script></script>` tag?

Comment: @UsamaMasood you are right, i thought i have to use JS syntax since I was working with JS

Comment: @Eddie no its not but i found to answer I just had to use HTML syntax since I was woking in a HTML file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are working with `.html` file, hence should use `HTML` comments if you are displaying contents into the web.

```
<!-- this is html comment -->
```

If you are using `JavaScript`, then use

```
/* js comment here */
```

or just

```
// js comment here
```

for one-line comments.